# Did Hinata actually feel this way about Yui?

Tags: angel-beats

In Episode 9 of *Angel Beats*, Hinata confesses his love to Yui, expresses a desire to marry her, and insists that the fact she was a wheelchair user when she was alive doesn't matter to him.

> This confession puts Yui at peace and allows her to move on.

For me, this confession came out of nowhere. I hadn't noticed any hints in previous episodes about Hinata feeling this way, so it came across as though he was just telling Yui what she needed to hear, rather than how he actually felt about her.

**Was Hinata truly in love with Yui?** If so, were there any hints of this earlier in the series?

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I've last seen this series, so forgive me if I make any mistakes.

It may have been  implied earlier on in the series that Hinata had a crush on Yuri, given his overprotectiveness of her, how flirty he acted with her at times (though perhaps that's just how he acted in general), and how dedicated and loyal to her he was; things did change slightly once Yui came into the picture.

Yui, much like Yuri, would eagerly abuse Hinata (poor guy can't catch a break), though she did so with wrestling holds, but he would begin to retaliate and the two got along well. The two would banter and have their spats just as very close friends or siblings, or perhaps even couples, would.

Minor plot spoilers ahead.

> Anyway, most importantly, he tells Otonashi at the
>  graduation (before he moves on) that he thinks he's saved
>  up a lot of luck, and that he'll use it all to meet with Yui. I
>  think that alone is enough to prove his feelings for her.

I sincerely doubt that, though he is kind and selfless, he would have the heart to lie to Yui's face about the one insecurity and dream that must have plagued her mind and heart since she first really took in what being paralyzed as she was meant.

As for earlier hints, well, I think it's just something you'll notice here and there while rewatching, as things happen that just make you think "Oh, he totally likes her."